# How do I move the livewire comonent NavigationMenu.php out of vendor

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I have a jetstream laravel app, I have made changed to the NavigationMenu.php file in the vendor directory.

I want to move this to the app/Http/Livewire directory so I can protect my changes and commit to git, but when I do, I am getting a file not found.

I have updated the namespace to, namespace App\Http\Livewire;

I am sure I am missing something stupid but I cannot for the life of me find it.

Any pointers,

Thanks

UPDATE:

I am adding code that will dynamically add tabs and manage some sessions.

Example of the code I have added to NavigationMenu.php is

```
public function openCustomer(Customer $customer) {
    // check customer is owner by auth user business
    if(auth()->user()->business_id != $customer->business_id) {
        abort(403, "Unauthorised Access");
    }

    $this->showCustomer = true;
    $this->customer = $customer;

    session(['customerId' => $customer->id]);

    return redirect()->route('customer.show', [$this->customer]);
}

public function closeTab(Request $request, $sessionVariable) {

    if($sessionVariable == 'showCustomer') {
        $this->showCustomer = false;
        $request->session()->forget(['customerId']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code what you added

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added some of the code above.

Comment: Why did you edit anything in the vendor folder? Why not override that class, or decorate it, such that the original class stays untouched?

Comment: I was trying to do that by moving the file into the app/Http/Livewire directory and then effectively using my own, but when I do I get file not found.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I do"?

Comment: When I move the file into the app/Http/Livewire directory from the vendor directory (so I can maintain myself) then when I refresh the file is not found. My understanding (which might be wrong) is that Laravel will look in both the vendor directory and / or the app/Http directory when resolving dependencies. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I doublt it looks in both positions. That depends on how you load that class after all.